# Как сгенерировать случайный вывод функции listaggs?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Eсть числовые значения (30, 31, 32, 33).

Как сгенерировать вывод (случайный), который может содержать отдельные значения из этого списка, их списки различной длины или `NULL`?

Что-то такое:

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 30, 31 |
| 2 | null |
| 3 | 32 |
| 4 | 33 |
| 5 | null |
| 6 | 31, 33 |
| 7 | null |
| 8 | 30 |

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Oracle SQL generate random output with listaggs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67423996/6571020) от участника user15746603 [удалён]</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/67423996

Answer (score 3):

Ниже способ генерации строк псевдослучайным образом, но при этом он совершенно детерминирован и воспроизводим. Для этого используется функция [ORA_HASH](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ORA_HASH.html#GUID-0349AFF5-0268-43CE-8118-4F96D752FDE6).

Если надо получить разные (но похожие) результаты, используйте третий аргумент `ORA_HASH`, чтобы задать seed, отличное от значения по умолчанию (=0). А если надо каждый раз получать разные результаты, в качестве seed задайте значение `dbms_random.value()`. В этом случае для всего запроса будет сгенерировано только одно случайное значение.

Также можно поиграться с верхней границей (в примере 2800), чтобы получить больше или меньше `NULL` и более короткие или длинные списки.

Запрос ([на db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0bd58ffe98dd3ceb8f76061ab7016fa8)):

```
with vals (value) as (
    select * from sys.ODCINumberList (30, 31, 32, 33)
),
ids (id) AS (
    select level from   dual connect by level <= 8
)
select id, ( 
    select listagg (
        case when ora_hash ((id * value), 10000, 0) < 2800 
             then value end, ',') within group(order by value)
    from vals) as vals
from ids;
```

Результат:

```
        ID VALS            
---------- ----------------
         1 <null>          
         2 32,33           
         3 <null>          
         4 30,31,33        
         5 30,31,33        
         6 33              
         7 <null>          
         8 30
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67426128) от участника [@mathguy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5683823/mathguy)</sub>